# git commit message showing file as 'copied' instead of 'modified'. What are the implications?

Tags: git

strong textgit status shows file as **modified**, however when commiting it shows the file as been **copied** ie:

git status
 modified:   foo/bar/baz.xml

git commit
 copied:     bar/foo/baz.xml -> foo/bar/baz.xml

Why is it showing this file as copied if it was not. The two files were identical before the change.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

git tracks content, not files. if two files are the same (or very much the same) git recognizes them as copied. there shouldn't be any implications from this

in your case both files were identical (100 %), so git has no possibility to know if the file was copied, or just accidentally happened to be the same.

don't worry, git only stores snapshots of the tree to the repository. you can control copy and rename detection for `git log` with parameters `-C` and `-M`, git will then try harder to find renames/copies

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know.

Comment: "git recognizes them as copied" vs "git has no possibility to know if the file was copied".  Seems like a contradiction. And in the case where the files are identical, I'd say it's quite the opposite. It *can* be certain the file was copied, precisely because it's identical.